# the_post_thumbnail('my_image_size') always outputs full image

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm developing a custom theme that uses several custom image sizes defined in my functions.php like this:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('featured_thumb', 175, 120, true);
```

I then get posts from the database and output on a page like this:

```
$featured=get_posts();
if ($featured)
{
          global $post;
          foreach($featured as $post)
          {
              setup_postdata($post);
              the_post_thumbnail('featured_thumb');
          }
          wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

But this code always outputs a full sized image. I can't figure out why - everything else seems to work alright (the_title(), the_permalink() etc) and it does get the correct image but not in the size I requested.

Does anyone know under what circumstances `the_post_thumbnail()` will ignore my image size, or what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: using WP 3.4.1

Comment: Did you regenerate your thumbnails or upload your image _after_ registering your custom sizes?

Comment: yeah I uploaded the images after writing that part of the theme - I *think*. To be sure I'll regenerate them again now though, that might be it.

Comment: Also there is a filter `post_thumbnail_size` to change the size. Has any plugin or your theme hooked into it?

Comment: not my theme, but couldn't speak for all plugins. I have none installed that do anything with media, but you never know. regenerating thumbnails at the moment

Comment: it was the thumbnails, I must have added the image size after putting the images up. what an idiot I am lol. someone put that in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Been there and done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that custom image sizes are **NOT** applied retroactively to images already uploaded.

Use a plugin like Regenerate Thumbnails or similar to generate them.